# How to remove tmpnam generated file in other folder from c:/ folder in c/c++

Tags: c++, c

My code is like this

```
  char buffer [L_tmpnam];
  char * pointer;
  tmpnam (buffer);
  strcat (buffer, "mux");
```

so it generates random ".mux" file in "C:\".
I want to remove those generated ".mux" file from "C:\" to "C:\Mytemp" folder .

Please help me.

Comment: you want to remove or move ??

Comment: Sorry I want to move file

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on Windows, you could use GetTempFileName, passing GetTempPath's result as the first argument.  Example on how to use it is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363875(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

according to `man tmpnam`

```
The pathname that is created, has a directory prefix P_tmpdir.  (Both L_tmpnam and P_tmpdir are defined in  <stdio.h>
```

change that string to particular directory you want to store file

Comment: I did not get you .Since I am new to c/c++.
Please help me .
I want some example like code.

Comment: @DharmveerKumar open this file "/include/stdio.h"  insude mingw folder and there is a macro P_tmpdir change that macro string definition to whatever location you want to create the tmp file

Comment: I changed In stdio.h #define _P_tmpdir   "\\strmTemp" from #define _P_tmpdir   "\\" ,But it did not reflect any thing still .mux file are getting created in c:\\ folder only

Comment: try to redefine this  # define P_tmpdir   "\\xyz"

Comment: I dont know i changed the path but it is still creating in c:\\ folder only

Comment: @DharmveerKumar if you are unable to use tmpnam than try this ..

char filename[] = "/tmp/mytemp.XXXXXX"; // template for our file.        
  int fd = mkstemp(filename);